Error: page.goto: WebKit encountered an internal error
Why do Playwright WebKit tests fail in VS Code but they do work in the terminal and how to fix?
When I run the example tests in VS Code - either the terminal or the VS Code testing plugin - Chromium and Firefox pass but with WebKit I get a failure:
Error: page.goto: WebKit encountered an internal error

When I run them in an external plain terminal window they pass - with the caveat that I also had to add {force: true} for the click, that is, I changed:
await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Get started' }).click();

to be:
await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');
await page.getByRole('link', { name: 'Get started' }).click({force: true});

and then it passes - but still only in an external terminal and not in the VS Code terminal window. Both show Node as version 18.20.4.
Ubuntu: version 24.01 LTS
Playwright: version 1.46.1

Please share a [mcve]--full code, config and a sample site that triggers the failure when executed. There is no goto in this code, and a simple .click() call does not reproduce any problems for me. Playwright should work exactly the same in the terminal as in VSCode--these are two different ways to launch the same program. Thanks.

I added the goto. Thanks. Yes there should be no difference where you run it.  Hence this question. There are.

Both work fine for me in VSCode and in the terminal, with and without force. I guessed and added my own boilerplate to make up for the lack of MRE--browser.launch() is a particularly important part because that's where the args are, which often have a dramatic impact on results. A MRE means I can look at your question, copy-paste the code locally, run it and see the exact same error as you. Without  that, it's virtually impossible to help.

It may be dependent on the terminal you use.
GDK_BACKEND=x11 DEBUG=pw:browser npx playwright test

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611875/gnome-maps-program-never-runs/612252#612252 and https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/23899
